# If the move is correct, which rule allows to go from line 4 to line 5 of this derivation? ( a question on the use of " falsum" in natural deduction)

Tags: logic, proof-writing, terminology, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction

Which natural deduction rule allows to derive any consequence from a contradiction in a conditional proof?

[image]

Comment: You've asked several questions about formal logic proofs and yet your proofs always follow some 'home-made' format ... I would highly recommend using some software for this; they typically have built-in checking, and so you learn the rules really quickly! Search for the Open Logic Project

Comment: [Here](https://proofmood.mindconnect.cc/en/Fitch/fitch.php) is a pretty nice online Fitch-based interface

Comment: Alternatively, [this one](http://maynards.site/items/fitch/full)

Comment: Contradiction Elimination. You can deduce anything from a contradiction.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is the *principle of explosion*, also known as *[ex falso quodlibert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion)*: from contradiction, anything follows.

In natural deduction, it says that if $\mathcal{D}$ is a derivation with conclusion $\bot$ then, for *every* formula $\varphi$, 
$$\dfrac{\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{\ \ \vdots \mathcal{D}}{\bot}}{\varphi}\scriptstyle\text{efq}$$
is a derivation with conclusion $\varphi$ and the same hypotheses as $\mathcal{D}$. For a reference, see [here](https://staff.fnwi.uva.nl/b.vandenberg3/Onderwijs/Proof_Theory_2016/handout_2.pdf) (p. 3)

---

Note that this rule can be used everywhere (not only in a conditional proof). Moreover, unlike the principle of *[reductio ad absurdum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reductio_ad_absurdum)*, *ex falso quodlibet* is accepted not only in classical logic but also in more constructive logics such as [intuitionistic logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intuitionistic_logic).

Answer (score 3):

In a typical Fitch system, this is the rule of $\bot \text{Elim}$:

$$\bot$$

$$\therefore \varphi$$

Here, by the way, is your whole proof in Fitch:

[image]